# javascript value from input

Tags: javascript, input

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        function changeText2(){
            var userInput = document.getElementById('userInput').value;
            var lnk = document.getElementById('lnk');
            lnk.href = "https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://facebook.com/" + userInput;
            lnk.innerHTML = lnk.href;
        }
        </script>


    <a href="" id=lnk></a> <br>
    <input type='text' id='userInput' value='' /> <br>
    <input type='button' onclick='changeText2()' value='Go'/>
```

I found that code on some website , i want to display an img not the url... Im new in javascript

Comment: Can you show the code you have so far?

Comment: Do you know any line of JavaScript? Do you know how to access DOM elements? Do you know how to get attributes of those elements? Do you know how to set the visibility of elements? If you can answer this questions with yes you should be able to do it.

Comment: @user2062819: Never ever post your code in a comment. Edit your question instead.

Comment: sorry ! , i have edit my question now :)

Comment: That code works exactly like you want it to. Proof here, I made no edits, just copy and paste: http://jsfiddle.net/77SPz/1/ What's the problem? You want to display an image? An image inside the link?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should work:

```
<a href="" id="fbLink" style="display:none;">
  <img src="YOUR_IMAGE_HERE.jpg"/>
</a>
<input type='text' id='userInput' value='' onchange="shLink()"/>
<script>
  function shLink(){
    if(document.getElementById("userInput").value!=""){
      if(document.getElementById("fbLink").style.display=="none"){
        document.getElementById("fbLink").style.display="";
        document.getElementById("fbLink").href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://facebook.com/"+document.getElementById("userInput").value;
      }
    }else{
      document.getElementById("fbLink").style.display="";
      document.getElementById("fbLink").href="";
    }
  }
<script>
```

The script will toggle the display of the link if there is a value entered into your input.  It will be called when the input value is changed (`onchange`).  Alternatively, you could use `onkeypress` to call the function whenever the user types something in your input.

Comment: That doesnt change the share link. if a user write " hello " i want the share url to be https://www.facebook.com/sharer/sharer.php?u=http://facebook.com/hello

Comment: Aha sorry hah! hmm , i dont get it to work :( ,it only displays " - " and its not clickable

Comment: yea i have dont that and my img displays but its not have any link to facebookshare?

Comment: Now it doesnt display my img at all "/ haha

Comment: It's been a long day apparently -_-